# How to proccess code in template

Tags: templates, meteor, each

i have a problem, i want to proccess with first element in foreach loop in template as PHP code example:

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($items as $rs){
 if($i==0){
   echo "first";
 }else{
  echo "not first";
 }
}
?>
```

Pls help me in template Meteor. Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code for us to work with? It's hard to help if there's no code to look at.

Comment: Thank Tokyovairable, with below answer, i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what you mean without some code of what you want to do, but I think you mean that you want to do something to the first item in a handlebars loop? If its that let me try and give it a shot:

This is a little tricky as the version of handlebars shipped with meteor does not yet do this so you need to do it manually.

**Use index values in the transform**

```
Template.hello.items = function() {
    var i = 0;
    return Items.find({}, { transform: function(doc) {
        i++;
        if(i==1) doc.first = true;
        return doc;
    }});
}
```

So this adds a virtual `first` field in your document if its the first one

**Your html loop**

```
{{#each items}}
    {{#if first}}
        This is the first item
    {{/if}}
    ....
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank Akshat so much.